# MVC Form DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my view I am building a form where the user select a country from a list of Countries.I get this error about Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Is there anything I am missing?

```
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(
                            x => x.selectedCountryId,
                            new SelectList(Model.ListOfCountries, "Value", "Text"),
                            "-- please select a Country--",
                            new { id = "ddlCountry", @class = "form-control" }
                    )
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.selectedCountryId)
```

Model

```
 [Required]
        public int? selectedCountryId{ get; set; }
```

Error

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.
```

Action Method

```
 public ActionResult Create(RequestFormViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                
            }

            return View(TemplateName, "");

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        RequestFormViewModel  result = new RequestFormViewModel ();

        try
        {
            var FormInfo = GetFormInfo();

            if (FormInfo != null)
            {
                result = FormInfo;


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        return View(TemplateName, result);
    }
```

Comment: your model is null or ListOfCountries is null   this will help you  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/binding-dropdownlist-in-mvc-in-various-ways-in-mvc-with-data/

Comment: @mohamed-adelI I get this on the form submit it loads the control fine

Comment: please share your action methods

Comment: action methods take in the model object

Comment: Dear you should have 2 action methods 1 for HttpGet and another one for HttpPost please share HttpGet action method to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action methods should be like below

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        //Way 1
        RequestFormViewModel model = new RequestFormViewModel();
        model.ListOfCountries = //Select from DB or Whatever
        return View(model);

        //Way 2
        ViewBag.ListOfCountries = //Select from DB or Whatever
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(RequestFormViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

and for view if you will use way 1 so you need to add ListOfCountries as [NotMapped] to your model or create Dto for this view
for way2 you need to bind dropdown from ViewBag instead of using ListOfCountries as a property

Comment: I get a HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found with this new logic

Comment: Could you please share updated view and action methods?